# Home internet not working with ubuntu

Tags: internet, dns

I've wanted to use Linux for a while but whenever I install it the internet doesn't work with my home wifi, it does work with my phone hotspot. I've tried changing some settings in my router and messing with the `resolv.conf` file (changing the nameserver). In the past I've installed ubuntu on my desktop and had the same issue, I was able to resolve it (I don't remember how to anymore) but after a little bit, it didn't work again. But today I made a ubuntu virtual machine and it connected to the internet just fine, so I tried to install it on my laptop but I'm having this issue.

Doing `lsb_release -a` gives:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Also whenever I ping google I get:

```
Ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution.
```

Because of this problem, ive never really been able to use ubuntu or any linux distro

Edit doing `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` returns:

```
Ping: connect: network is unreachable
```

And doing `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` returns:

```
Lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Aug 19 2021 /etc/resolv.conf ->
../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

I should also note that I'm using the installer while doing this

doing `iwconfig` gives

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"HiddenNetwork"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 00:19:92:9D:EE:B7   
          Bit Rate=52 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=63/70  Signal level=-47 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:25   Missed beacon:0
```

doing `nmcli device wifi list` gives:

```
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID                  MODE   CHAN  RATE    
SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY 
        32:FC:EB:9A:03:15  Verizon LM-G900 0315  Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  87      ▂▄▆█  WPA2     
*       00:19:92:9D:EE:B7  HiddenNetwork         Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  82      ▂▄▆█  WPA2     
        62:45:B0:81:AE:85  --                    Infra  153   0 Mbit/s    20      ▂___  WEP
```

doing `uname -a` gives

```
Linux ubuntu 5.11.0-27-generic #29~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 11
15:58:17 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm not sure about the wifi adapter, but I'm using a dell Inspirion 7405 2 in 1

My home wifi name is "Hidden network". I tried changing it but I had the same problem

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134323/discussion-on-question-by-idklmao-home-internet-not-working-with-ubuntu).

Comment: I cant enter the chat anymore

Comment: It's working for me: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134323/discussion-on-question-by-idklmao-home-internet-not-working-with-ubuntu

Comment: For me it brings me to a page that says: Why has my post been blocked due to "spam and abuse from my network"?

Comment: It brings me there if I try to join any room

Comment: I suggest that you ask the question here. https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions I haven't experienced that before.

Comment: I submitted a ticket already; its alright, the other problem that I mentioned is making it so my computer wont even turn on, so it might take me a little time to do anything with this problem.

Comment: Here was my last message: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/xpZQ5RJw6t/

Comment: I can still see the chat, but trying to join it redirects me to that page

Comment: Until the chat issue is resolved, I suggest that, as you are able, you address the points I listed.

Comment: Yes, I did it this morning, i put the results in a document. But because of my other problem, my computer will not turn back on

Comment: @Idklmao your IP is on a blocklist likely due to abuse - not necessarily your abuse but others' abuse.  As you are a new user and haven't hit the rep level to be considered a 'trusted user' you are subject to rate limits and blocks.  Right now, the IP address you were most recently on is on the spam block list, and there's nothing we can do.  (This said, a lot of verizon wireless IPs are actually on this list and if you are using your phone all the time you're very likely to get an IP here or there that has been used for spamming in the past)

Comment: Thats odd, im now able to go in the chat with my home wifi, but not my hotspot or mobile data. I wasnt able to yesterday. I even tried on my school wifi and i was blocked yesterday

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with Ubuntu 22.04 - my home network hasn't worked some time after the installation of Docker CE. The root cause was that Docker reserved some CIDR range for containers, while the DNS server was in this range.

The solution was to create / update file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` with the following JSON:

```json
{
  "bip": "172.31.0.1/16"
}
```

And then restart Docker with the following command:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

I've found description of the issue as well as the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1336567/installing-docker-ce-in-ubuntu-18-04-breaks-internet-connectivity-of-host).

Comment: Man you saved my a** off, thanks so much!  
Never would've thought it would cause this issue...